# How to send byte array using twisted python

Tags: python, function, arrays, twisted

Here, in sendQuote method I want to send a byte array but twisted provides transport write method which takes string. How can i send a byte array in response using Twisted. Thanks.

```
class QuoteProtocol(protocol.Protocol):
  def __init__(self, factory):
    self.factory = factory

  def connectionMade(self):
    self.sendQuote()

  def sendQuote(self):
    #self.file.write(bytearray([0x00, 0x31, 0x34, 0x32, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x31, 0x11, 0x0c, 0x00, 0xfd, 0x09, 0x00, 0x2f, 0xe7, 0x5e, 0x3a, 0x08, 0x3c, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x49, 0x95]))
    self.transport.write("Quote reecevied")

  def dataReceived(self, data):
    print "Received quote:", data
    self.transport.loseConnection()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to send a `bytearray`?  Python's native string type is effectively an array of bytes - an immutable one.  As you've already observed, `transport.write` will accept a string.  So it will let you send whatever array of bytes you've got that you need to send.

If you have some data around that is already in a `bytearray` instance for some good reason then you can construct a `bytes` instance from it using easily: `bytes(your_bytearray)`.